# How to create a dynamic variable in a loop in order to use less lines in code. VB NET

Tags: vb.net, dynamic

I have a set of 81 buttons in my vb net studio. They are sorted 9x9 creating a sudoku patern. (Image 1)

Image 1: https://prnt.sc/10d49ci

When i click the Generate button it generates random numbers from 1 to 9 into MyArr(9,9).
Next i want to set the buttons to those values of MyArr() according to their position.

For example Button1 named Cell00 should i write "Cell00.Text = MyArr(0,0)"

For Button2 named Cell01 should i write "Cell01.Text = MyArr(0,1)" and so on.

Is there any way to set those values without writing one by one until last Button? My Buttons names are Cell00, Cell01,Cell02....Cell08 next line Cell10,Cell11 and so on.
I try to do this in a loop `Cell & i.ToString & j.ToString.Text = MyArr(i,j)` check the image 2

Image 2: https://prnt.sc/10d4djn <--- Code here

The .Text added as example. I suppose something like this but does not work.

For example `Cell01.Text = MyArr(0,1)`
Any idea?

Comment: Are you looking for Macro Substitution?  If I was in your situation, I would rename the buttons into something a little more aligned with your array indexes.  btn_Cell_"i"_"j" then it's simple to construct a string in your loop and use the controls collection  to locate your target button by name

Comment: `Dim idx = 1 Me.Controls($"Cell{idx:00}").Text =  MyArr(0,1).ToString()`. Where `Me` should be replaced by the instance of the container if it's not the Form (it looks like it could be a TableLayoutPanel). Set `idx` in a loop. -- You should also drop the Randomizer thing and use the [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random) class.